# Accessing localisation ResourceBundle inside JavaFX FXML Controller

Tags: java, javafx, internationalization, resourcebundle, fxmlloader

I'm trying to add localisation functionality to a JavaFX program using FXML. From what I understand, when you create a `FXMLLoader` object, you can pass a `ResourceBundle` into the `FXMLLoader`'s [constructor](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.net.URL,java.util.ResourceBundle)) like so:

```java
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Application.class.getResource("main-menu.fxml"),
        ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.example.myApp.MainMenu");
```

However, I want to be able to access the `ResourceBundle` inside one of my controllers, so that I can do something like this:

```java
class MainMenuController {
    // ...
    @FXML
    protected void onButtonClick() {
        welcomeText.setText(localisationBundle.getString("greetMessage");
    }
    // ...
}
```

I have put the following initialize method inside my main menu controller...

```java
@FXML
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle bundle) {
    this.localisationBundle = bundle;
}
```

...but it does not get invoked when the program is run, and thus `localisationBundle` is null when my button is pressed. The initialize method only gets invoked when I change its signature to have no parameters.
I have seen a suggestion on StackOverflow that my controller should implement [Initializable](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html), however the documentation says that this has been superceded.

My question is: Is there a way to get access to the `ResourceBundle` that is passed to the `FXMLLoader`'s constructor? Is `Initializable` the only way I can do this or is there a better way?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: That should work. If your `initialize()` method is not getting invoked something else is wrong in your setup: create and post a [mre]. Note you can also inject the resource bundle using `@FXML` on a field called `resources` (though this is undocumented behavior, as far as I can tell).

Comment: `@FXML private ResourceBundle resources;` it injects like other fxml annotated fields, no fx:id required.

Comment: In addition to the load method with the resources parameter, there are a couple of [alternate methods for specifying a resource bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46103533/specify-resourcebundle-within-fxml-file-in-javafx), they all achieve the same thing.

Comment: @James_D It's _sort of_ [documented behavior](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html), but the documentation is... poor.

Comment: Ah, actually, yes. The `initialize()` method that takes parameters appears *not* to get invoked if you don't implement `Initializable`. If you don't want to implement the interface, use injection instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `initialize()` method taking the `URL` and `ResourceBundle` parameters only gets invoked if you implement `Initializable`. This interface has not been deprecated, so I think it is fine to use that approach; however it has been superseded by (to quote the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html)

> automatic injection of `location` and `resources` properties into the controller.

To do this, you need:

```
public class MainMenuController {

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources ;

    // if needed:
    @FXML
    private URL location ;

    // ...
    @FXML
    protected void onButtonClick() {
        welcomeText.setText(resources.getString("greetMessage");
    }
    // ...
}
```